# Saving an OpenXML SpreadsheetDocument to a stream

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am reading a creating an OpenXml SpreadsheetDocument from an external Excel file stream, and I add some formula and values.

However, when I try to save it to a stream, it loses most of its data and not capable of being opened.

Here is the code I used:

```
var stream= new MemoryStream();
.
.
.
spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save(stream);
stream = new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray());
stream.Position = 0;

return stream;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are two `MemoryStream` really necessary?

Try to flush `tempStream` before deriving a new `MemoryStream` from it.
Example:

```
spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save(tempStream);
tempStream.Flush();
stream = new MemoryStream(tempStream.ToArray());
```

Also, do you save the output to a file or read it from memory? `MemoryStream`'s content is logically lost as soon as you `.Close()` it.

Comment: Two MomoryStream are not necessary indeed.

I am reading the output from the memory and render it into the browser. And I am not invoking .Close() hence I called "spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save(tempStream);".

I use the suggested "Flush()" but the browser can not render the output. it says : "The workbook is possibly corrupted or uses a file format that's not supported."

Comment: @BaronNtambwe, provided you didn't already solve this (sorry, was on vacation), can you show us the complete function? Did you try to save the stream to a file, is such a file readable?

Comment: I ended up using a combination of OpenXML and CloseXML. I do the processing with OpenXML, and pass the stream to CloseXML and save it.

And it worked well that way.